# Creating pdf and sending it via email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, wicked-pdf

I am working on a phone billing application.
I have created simple Rails App with 3 tables Client, Invoice, CallRecord.
I can browse my dummy data and all works fine.
I would like to add a feature to send invoices to clients via email.
I was thinking about creating a simple link/button on the invoice#show view: Send invoice.

I was looking at WickedPDF gem as it will generate pdf from HTML.

I have three questions:

1) Is WickedPDF good for what I am looking for? 
   I am not trying to serve PDF to a user browsing the website. I don't want to make it downloadable.
   I just need to generate it and save it when the Send Invoice is clicked, if it hasn't been generated already. And then email it using rails mailer to a client keeping the generated copy on the server(all this will be done in a custom controller action).

2) Where would be the best place to store this generated pdf's? Custom folder in Assets folder, public folder?

3)How would you go about saving files using rails? I have done a bit of rails but I have never done anything this direction.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can actually use [Wicked-PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#super-advanced-usage) directly without the
   controllers by:

   pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('`<h1>Hello There!</h1>`')

or

```
WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
  render_to_string('templates/pdf.html.erb', :layout => 'pdfs/layout_pdf'),
  :footer => {
    :content => render_to_string(:layout => 'pdfs/layout_pdf')
  }
) # which is awesome
```

2. Storing them should be in the public folder in a similar format:

   public/users/:user_id/:invoice_id
3. you should consider doing that as a delayed job using [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or something because the generation would take time and the user should not wait until it is generated.

Comment: khaled-gomaa - how would you save that generated pdf onto the disk? Let say I will generate it in a controller as you have sugested **pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(..)** Is File.open(...) {...} the way to go? I know you have suggested sidekiq for pdf generation. How would I save it then if the controller quits straight after. My sidekiq knowledge is limited. It is probably another question but if you could update your answer with this info I will appreciate it.